# Retrieve user first name, last name and email without account linking

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, account-linking

I've implemented my action using Google Sign-in and Account Linking but I've realised that this
may not be necessary as I just need to retrieve the user email address,
name and last name during the conversation for the sole purpose of sending an email and forget about it after.

With account linking the user interacting with my agent is asked to "register" an account with  which could discourage users to proceed.

I've found this agent which simply asks "in order to get your email address can we access your google account"...
https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000f63f47d43d

How can that be achieved?

Thanks,
Salvo

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to consider is that it can be difficult to speak an email address using voice, making it possible for a transcription error. Some names may also be transcribed incorrectly, which may result in a bad user experience.

The second is that using account linking is the recommended way generally. As noted in the [platform policy](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/policies/general-policies#user_data):

> All Actions must: ... Request sensitive user data via the Permissions API; All requests for a user's location and name.

Comment: I tried the action that the OP posted as an example. It asks the user for permission to use their email, I thought it would be Google Sign-in, but the user isnt informed about any terms of service during the flow. Its just a simple one question accountlink

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that action, I'm just specifying what the platform policy is supposed to be.

Comment: @Jordi yes that's exactly what I'd like to achieve, "a simple one question accountlink" but  I cannot find any documentation on how to ask just for first name, last name and email permissions, without account linking.